# How do we store a pfx file in CertStore which is protected using password, retrieve it using password

Tags: c#, certificate

Can a pfx certificate stored in Cert Store be protected using a password?

I have following function which is trying to export pfx file using password and store to client store.

```
public bool StoreCertificate(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation,X509Certificate2 cert,String password,
        X509KeyStorageFlags keyStoreFlags = X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
{
        var store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);

        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

            byte[] pfx = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password);
            cert = new X509Certificate2(pfx, password, keyStoreFlags);
            store.Add(cert);
            store.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            m_log.LogError("Add to certificate store failed" + error.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (store != null)
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
        return true; 
}
```

But while retrieving I was able to retrieve everything without any password using following simple function.

```
public X509Certificate2 LoadFromStore(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, String password, String subject, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStoreFlags = X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet )
{
        var store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);

        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

            foreach (var c in store.Certificates)
            {
                if (c.Subject.Contains(subject))
                {
                    return c;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (store != null)
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

Is there any easy way of protecting the contents of certificate which includes private key while storing to CertStore?.

Or,

Do we need to associate with an use account?.